# Why is nobody using electron compile?

Tags: node.js, electron

I've been trying out electron compile, and it works great. But I don't see any projects using it.

So is there any reason why most electron projects are using webpack, gulp, etc. and not electron compile? Is there anything wrong with electron compile for big projects or something?

Comment: Hey there I know you seek an answer but asking on StackOverflow for an opinion about frameworks is not really a good idea since if it comes to opinions developer go offtopic very quickly e.g "tabs vs spaces", "amiga vs atari" or "mac vs linux" without awnsering any questions. ;)  Best take a look at the FAQ https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Hammster Got it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** there is nothing wrong with it, and no I don't use it either. It is just that you can archive the same with webpack, which has more users brings no drawbacks and is probably more frequently maintained. It all depends on your own preferences which you want to use.